# Cinnamon Annoying Volume Notification Popup - osd

Tags: themes, notification, cinnamon, notify-osd

I'm using Cinnamon, version 2.2.16
Everytime I change the volume or brightness this annoying popup appears. It blocks the middle of the screen, it's not just like ubuntu's notify-osd which appears on top right corner.Please help, can I somehow remove it??

[image: img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** As of the new Cinnamon version 2.6 (currently in RC phase with Linux Mint 17.2), it is now possible to completely disable the media key OSD:

*System Settings* → *Preferences* → *Notifications* → *Media keys OSD size*: *Disabled*

I assume this requires the Cinnamon version of the control center.

---

This doesn't come from Cinnamon specifically, but from GNOME 3, from which Cinnamon was forked. Unlike  most other notifications or popups, these are shown directly by the desktop and not managed by some notification library like libnotify. They are hardcoded to show up when the volume or brightness is changed using the default key triggers.

To fix it, use your own hotkeys for XF86AudioRaiseVolume, XF86AudioLowerVolume, XF86MonBrightnessUp and XF86MonBrightnessDown, using commands not bound to the desktop.

As an example, you can use the following commands, but you have to install the package `xbacklight` before.

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5% #increase sound volume
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- -5% #decrease sound volume
xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```

---

Normally, meaning using Cinnamon's default theme or the Mint-X theme, this thing looks much nicer and is transparent. Then I like it. But the way it looks in your screenshot, it really is annoying. You may want to consider installing the Linux Mint default themes. You can get them by installing the `mint-themes` package and its dependencies. They are, however, only included in the Mint repos, so it might be easiest to get and install the debian package archives from a rebecca/main mirror, like from [here](http://linux-mint.froonix.org/pool/main/m/). But watch out, it could break things in Ubuntu (it certainly breaks Ubuntu's custom LibreOffice theme)

Comment: I was looking everywhere for this. It worked like a charm!

Comment: When I type `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5%`, it changes the volume, but no notification is displayed. OSD size in preferences is set to "medium", not "disabled". Do you know why the volume change notification is not being displayed?